# Rebulid a variable that sent by reference

Tags: c++, reference, rebuild

this is my code

```
void SMatrix::pow(int power, SMatrix & result)
{
        if (this->rowSize != this->colSize || this->rowSize != result.rowSize || this->colSize != result.colSize || power <= 0)
        {
            delete & result;
            result = new SMatrix (result.rowSize, result.colSize);
        }
}
```

Im trying to delete this result in this case, and send it as new `SMatrix`. How can i do it? (`reuslt = newM`..... ask me for `SMatrix *`, but it doesn't work with &).

In the main i can build it like that:
SMatrix * s = new SMatrix(4, 4);
or 
SMatrix s(4, 4);
(pointer or not).

Comment: What happens if `result` is on the stack? Please have a rethink

Comment: Why do you `delete &result`? Are you sure the caller will pass a dynamically allocated object? If they don't, bamm! Just use value semantics. `result = SMatrix (result.rowSize, result.colSize);` or `result.swap(SMatrix(result.rowSize, result.colSize));` if you have an efficient swap. And get rid of the `delete`.

Comment: Does this code compile? It is wrong on so many fronts

Comment: It would be legal to write `result.~SMatrix(); new(&result) SMatrix(result.rowSize, result.colSize);` . But this is more error-prone and probably less efficient than using assignment as in Mats Petersson's solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is just "doing it wrong".

If you have a reference argument, then the implied effect is that the ownership of any pointer to it belongs to the caller.

```
void SMatrix::pow(int power, SMatrix & result)
{
        if (this->rowSize != this->colSize || this->rowSize != result.rowSize || this->colSize != result.colSize || power <= 0)
        {
            delete & result;
            result = new SMatrix (result.rowSize, result.colSize);
        }
}
```

If your `SMatrix` doesn't have a proper `operator=`, then you should have one. In other words, the correct thing should happen if you do:

```
        if (rowSize != colSize || rowSize != result.rowSize || colSize != result.colSize || power <= 0)
        {
            result = SMatrix (result.rowSize, result.colSize);
        }
```

(Note that I removed both the `delete` line and the `new` operator)

If this, for some reason, won't work correctly, then you need to fix that, not rely on how the orignal data was allocated.

Comment: You could have got rid of `this->` into the bargain

Comment: Yes, it's unnecessary, but I generally don't edit the OP's code more than necessary - it just makes it harder to spot the "actually needed" changes, vs. "cosmetic/non-functional" changes.

Answer (score 2):

```
        delete & result;
        result = new SMatrix (result.rowSize, result.colSize);
```

You can't `delete` an object and then call `operator=` on it. You're doing the equivalent of this:

```
std::string* j = new std::string ("hello");
delete j;
*j = "goodbye"; // Oops, there's no string whose value we can set
```

I think you probably just want `result = SMatrix (result.rowSize, result.colSize);`. You want to change the value of `result`, you don't want to delete or create anything dynamic.

Comment: For a start in the posters code `result` is not a pointer - so there is a mismatch with `new`. Also the poster is using `result.xxxx` in the construction

Comment: @EdHeal I know his code doesn't use a pointer. I switched it to a pointer (keeping everything else the same) to make things easier to understand. I don't know what you mean by "mismatch with new".

Comment: @EdHeal Right, so? If you're talking about what he has on the right side of the `=` sign, it doesn't matter. Calling `operator=` would be incorrect regardless of what you're trying to set it equal to.

Comment: LHS is a different type to the RHS

Comment: @EdHeal Fortunately in C++ one can write converting constructors and assignment operators. But I suspect this is actually the problem OP is running into, i.e. they are yet to run into a runtime memory problem.

Comment: @EdHeal Nothing wrong with that, since the thing on the left is a class. That might also be an error in his code, but it's much more important that he understand that he's invoking `operator=` on an object that no longer exists.